# Fetch EFS Details from the ENI - AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-efs

I want to fetch the details of ENI such as EFS id and mount point from the ENI ID, I'm trying to figure out the aws- cli command for it.
My input would be ENI Id

From the Interface I can easily fetch these information but somehow I'm not able to get it through the Cli.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it's possible to directly query for file systems filtering by ENI id. You have to iterate over all your file systems, fetching the respective mount targets along with them. Then, you can filter the targets by their ENI id, obtaining the matching file system, and eventually querying for its access points if you need to output the mount points.

Here is a shell script that does what I described. Note the placeholder at line 3, you can put your input interface id there.

```
for EFS_ID in $(aws efs describe-file-systems --query 'FileSystems[*].FileSystemId' --output text); do
  for ENI_ID in $(aws efs describe-mount-targets --file-system-id "$EFS_ID" --query 'MountTargets[*].NetworkInterfaceId' --output text); do
    if [[ "$ENI_ID" = "<your-eni-id>" ]]; then
      echo "File System id: $EFS_ID\n"
      echo "Access point:"
      aws efs describe-access-points --file-system-id "$EFS_ID"
    fi
  done
done
```